# Git switching between branches

Tags: git, svn, branch

I'm still new with Git so apologies for the noob question. Previously I've used SVN and worked on projects that had multiple branches. I'd have multiple VS solutions open at once, or at the very least switch frequently between them.

With Git I understand having multiple branches open at one is not possible, so switching between them becomes rather tedious.

Just curious as to what the best strategy would be for accommodating this kind of workflow.

Comment: When you say you have "multiple VS solutions open at once", does that mean you have multiple copies of the project checked out at the same time, into different directories?

Answer (score 3):

In `git`, it is perfectly normal to frequently switch between branches locally, because such switches do not require a round trip to the server and are fast.

Also, if you merely need to see Branch A's version of a file while working on Branch B, you can just use `git show A:path/to/file` on the command line.

Similarly, if you want to do a `diff` between two branches version of a file, you can do

```
git diff A B -- path/to/file
```

If you really want to have multiple branches checked out at once, then just `git clone` the repository multiple times, and check out a different branch on each clone.